# including other files in Google Script html file is showing the code not the included file

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some simple code that is just not working and I cannot understand why. I turn to the genius here. I have read the best practices and the documentation. I have also looked at examples and I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Entire Code.gs file::

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

Entire getDataSetOne.gs file::

```
function getDataSetOne() {
  try {
    // get data & declare vars
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18ledRrqCF2hvUhe6MDJPMG2E1OdoSqqoprV86Y77JvA');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var holidays = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    var tableData = "<table class='table'>";

    // parse data
    holidays.forEach(function(holiday){
      tableData += "<tr>";
      holiday.forEach(function(holidayInfo){
        tableData += "<td>" + holidayInfo + "</td>";

      })
      tableData += "</tr>";
    })

    //close table
    tableData += "</table>";

    // convert holidays to Json obj
    jsTojson(holidays);

    console.log(jsTojson(holidays))
    
    return tableData;
  } catch (err) {
     alert(err.message);
  }
}
```

HTML Snippet::

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>
          Holidays
        </h2>
        <p>
          <?!= include('getDataSetOne'); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn" href="#"></a>
        </p>
      </div>
```

The HTML file loads and "" is in place of the actual dataset.

[Image of what is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ8IO.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you put the name of a function rather than a file but I could be wrong.  But your include function is correct

Comment: I always name the file the same as the function name. It helps me keep things in order.

Comment: I usually have many more that just one function in a file.  But the include looks okay so it should  work.

Comment: It may not matter but I usually don't have a semicolon

Comment: Did you deploy it as a webapp or try it as a dialog?

Comment: Oh is the function a gs function because that would be incorrect and if it's a javascript file then it should be an html file

Comment: @Cooper It is a Web App. Also, getDataSetOne is a .gs

Comment: What are you seeing in the console when you try to run it?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]  We need more informatioin so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Please show us index.html and possibly getDataSetOne.html

Comment: @Cooper the console shows no errors. I think that is the minimum amount of code. The "Google Script Code::" is literally my whole Code.gs file.

Comment: @Cooper Updated original post.

Comment: You're not  creating a template and evaluating.

Comment: Ah that's it?  I wish I was as smart as @TheMaster  And including a gs file is not going to work.

Comment: @TheMaster Can you be more clear? I am not understanding? What would be the template? the getDataSetOne or index?

Comment: See [create template from file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))  index.html should be a template

Comment: This: `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');` should be a template+evaluate()

Comment: @Cooper We all sometimes just need a different set of eyes to look at the code differently

Comment: @Cooper I tried your answer, got the error :: The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.

Comment: Yeah I'll let someone else answer because I don't really have the interest in doing it for you. I don't mind helping with a few comments but you're going to have to figure it for yourself

Comment: @Cooper Okay I see where I went wrong... I copied the getDAtaSetOne to an HTML and enclosed it in the <script> tag... It is working now! Thank you both for your help!

Comment: As @Cooper already said, you can't `include` a `.gs` file. It should be a `.html` file.

Comment: @JustinWorsham Consider adding a answer with your  explanations and modifications.  See [answer]